# Creating backlinks using non-standard example domains

Tags: discussion

In [this recent question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/368213/should-a-rest-api-return-a-500-internal-server-error-to-indicate-that-a-query-re) the OP uses `domain.com` as an example domain.

While this seems rather intuitive keep in mind that `domain.com` is an actual live domain. This resulted in an [answer linking to said domain](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/368230/197693).

I feel this is wrong since the actual `domain.com` has nothing to do with the question. There is a reason we have `example.com`.

I thought about raising a custom moderator flag to bring this issue to attention.

Am I overly pedantic or should the question and answers be edited?  <sup>Both may apply</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's absolutely no reason to flag these posts. In fact, if I saw that flag in the flag queue, I'd decline them with the "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention" reason. Edits do not require a moderator - any user can at least suggest edits and put the post into the edit queue and users with at least 2000 reputation can make edits immediately. Neither of these requires moderator attention.

That said - I've edited all of the posts to use `example.com`.

Comment: I do not have the reputation to edit all posts at one swoop and did not want to put four posts in the suggested edit queue for something this mundane. Thank you for clarifying flagging is not the right course of action in a case like this.

Comment: @SørenD.Ptæus I'm not sure why you didn't want to put the posts into the suggested edit queue. That would be the best thing to do in the future for things like this. If, for some reason, the edits are declined, then coming to Meta is the next step.